# "Error creating directory: Input/output error" in Lubuntu, and in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I just switched the system of my netbook from Windows 7 to Lubuntu and everything is quite great.

However, one of my previous partitions is resistant to file changes (create files, folders, rename, deletion, copy). The massage `Error creating directory: Input/output error` pops out during the creation process.

But the other two partitions are working well.
I don't know what is the matter about this partition. Could you please help me with this?

#### Edit

When I changed my system into Ubuntu, the same problem also appeared.

There are some screenshots during the process of Creation, Deletion and Rename.

[image: Error during creating folder]

[image: Error during deleting file]

#### Edit 2

Another strange thing is that although the error pops out, the deleted files do disappear, but I can never delete the file enclosing folder, it says that `it's not an empty folder`.

Here is the output with "mount"

```
zcx@zcx-X101H:~$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup 
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=zcx)
/dev/sda5 on /media/zcx/A43AD4673AD437CE type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/zcx/1402CA8902CA6F74 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/zcx/3C20BED720BE96FC type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
zcx@zcx-X101H:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/723212/edit) your question with the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the permissions are not set correctly, so you won't have write access, especially if this is an NTFS partition. If the partitions are automatically mounted, they may be set to the uid/gid of the automounter's process (I don't have lubuntu but I suspect it is not your primary user).

For NTFS in particular, take a look at `man ntfs-3g` (online [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html)) for the "uid=" and "gid=" options.

If you can open a terminal and cd to the problem partition, you can check `ls -la` and compare to the working ones (1st column shows permissions, 3rd and 4th columns of output are the user and group id respectively -- it may give you a hint about what is different between the partitions).

Comment: Hi, neocpp, I check the permissions of these partitions by "ls -la", and found that they have the similar permission.

Comment: I also changed the system into Ubuntu, but still can not edit files or folders in this partition. But when I use WinPE in flash drive, I can delete or add file and folders in this volume.

Comment: The partition may simply be mounted read-only for some reason (I believe if it is marked dirty and needs to be checked this would be the case). Can you add in the output of the `mount` command to your question?

Comment: I just remembered that I've had occasional issues with certain file managers themselves. I don't think this will apply to you directly since you seem to be using Nautilus, but sometimes with Thunar you can get permission errors whereas performing the same action in a terminal is successful (e.g. you can't create a new folder using the file manager, but running `mkdir` works).

Comment: Hi, neocpp, "mkdir" is also not work in my case. The output is "mkdir: cannot create directory 'new': input/output error"

Comment: @Chunxing At least from what's provided I'm not sure what the problem is (it looks like the partition is mounted read-write). One last thing to do is to try the mkdir command under sudo (e.g. `sudo mkdir testdir`). Regarding your update, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48227/cannot-remove-some-directory-directory-not-empty)

Comment: Hi, neocpp, I have also tried mkdir, and it did not work.

Comment: Great thanks for your kind help. I appreciate it a lot. Now I have backup the data in that partition and reallocate and format it, and it works currently.